# Is there a way to delay the launch of the Finder app when logging in in macOS?

Tags: macos, finder, startup, external-disk, login

In recent macOS releases (Ventura/Sonoma), I have had this problem where, when I reboot and log in, the Finder launches **before** macOS has finished mounting my external (Thunderbolt) volumes. I don't know if it's because I have a lot of external volumes or it is for some other reason, but I have had lots of external volumes for a long time and this never used to be a problem.

Because the volumes are not (yet) available when the Finder launches, this causes the Finder to **fail to reopen** windows showing the contents of folders on these external volumes that I might have left open before I rebooted. I also have shortcuts to such folders in my Finder toolbar, and because of the Finder launching too soon, the shortcuts **lose their icon** and turn into question marks.

Manually relaunching the Finder at the end of the login process, when the volumes are all finally mounted, does bring the icons back in the Finder toolbar (because, of course, the shortcuts now work properly again). But unfortunately it doesn't bring back these Finder windows showing the contents of folders on the external volumes that I had left open when I rebooted. So those windows are lost, and I have to recreate them manually, each and every time I reboot.

So my question is: Is there any way to **delay** the launch of the Finder at login so that macOS has time to mount the external volumes, and so that I do not lose the Finder windows showing the contents of folders on the external volumes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finder is normally responsible for these mounts.  What process have you come up with for mounting these outside of Finder?  That would seem to be the problem.

Comment: I am not doing anything outside of the Finder. As my post indicates, the problem is with the Finder itself. When I log in after a reboot, the Finder launches before the drives have finished mounting. And I am referring to the normal mounting process initiated by macOS itself. There's nothing special about these drives. They are mounted by macOS. It's just that, apparently, they are not mounted by macOS fast enough so that they are available by the time the Finder itself launches. No alternative mounting mechanism is involved.

Comment: I have similar problem with other apps (which use external SSDs) starting before macOS has mounted all the external volumes. macOS is particularly slow mounting external HDD with lots of snapshots (e.g. Time Machine and CCC volumes). My solution is to stop auto mounting of HDD, so that external SSDs get mounted first.

Comment: I didn't mention this in my initial post, but sometimes the mounting is so slow that I also have to deal with Plex Media Server having launched too soon and having failed to find the hard drives, which causes it to stop monitoring them. What did you use to stop auto mounting of some drives? I've just started using TinkerTool System, and it seems to work (to stop macOS from mounting those drives that I do not need and only mount the ones I need), but it makes no difference for my Finder problem.

Comment: Gilby, I'm intrigued by your mention of “external HDDs with lots of snapshots”. While I don't use Time Machine or CCC, I use SuperDuper! to backup all my volumes on HDDs, including my startup volume (on the internal SSD). Is there an easy way to determine how many snapshots there are on external backups of this startup volume? Just curious.

Comment: Answering my own question, looks like Disk Utility can show the snapshots. Based on what it says, I only have ONE snapshot on HDD drives that have any, so that's probably not the problem (although it does take Disk Utility an awful long time to refresh and display the snapshot).

Comment: You can modify /etc/fstab to prevent auto mounting of specific disks.  But looks like lots of snapshots is not your problem.

Comment: Right. I'm pretty sure that this is what TinkerTool System does behind the scenes, and it works fine. But that's not the problem. The problem is that those disks that I do want mounted do not mount fast enough to be available when the Finder launches and tries to reopen its windows. Only workaround I've found after reboot is to log in first with a different user name and password, for an account with nothing running, and then log out of that account and log back in with my main user account. Awkward.